# How i exactly determine if variable not defined in file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

Having following text file which contain `ip_address` variable. File as follows

```
$ cat file
ip_address=10.78.1.0
filename=test.bin
```

Now having bash script which check if `ip_address` defined( or available or not)

```
#!/bin/bash

for list in $(cat file)
do
    eval $list
done

${ip_Address:?Error \$IP_Address is not defined}

[ -z ${ip_Address:-""} ] && printf "No IPaddress\n" || echo "$ip_Address"
```

Now if my file not contain line for `ip_address` variable then script is break here but if there then it again check if `ip_adress` contain any value of not.

But i not want to break my script instead if variable not available the want to do something

like

```
#!/bin/bash

for list in $(cat file)
do
    eval $list
done

if [ variable not available ]
then
    #do something
else
    #check variable set or not
    [ -z ${ip_Address:-""} ] && printf "No IP address\n" || echo "$ip_Address"
fi
```

Having tried using `-z` flag (actually this flag check variable empty or not but not for availability of variable) like this

```
if [ -z  $ip_Address ]
then
    #do something
else 
    #rest of code
fi
```

But it fails in following conditions

case 1:
If my file as follows

```
$ cat file
  filename=test.bin
```

then it must go in `if..` block and it does.So it's not problem

case 2 :

If my file as follows

```
$ cat file
  ip_address=
  filename=test.bin
```

then it must go in `else..` block but it does't. So it's problem

So how can i differentiate if variable defined or variable available in bash?

Comment: does this file also a shell script?

Comment: No it's simple file like text file.

Comment: The `eval` loop near the beginning looks awkward and dangerous.  If the file is executable code, why do you not simply `source file`?

Comment: @tripleee you are right but `source` seems not proper for simple text file right?

Comment: Why not?  If you can `eval` it you can certainly `source` it as well.

Comment: @tripleee ok so i can source also text file right?

Comment: I don't think I can say it any clearer.  Bash does nothing to verify that the file you `source` is not a "binary" file, or a "text" file, or an "executable" file.  If it can be read, it can be sourced.

Comment: @Jayesh A shell script *is* a text file, just one whose text is recognized by the shell as valid commands.

Comment: I too thought the `[ ! -z "${ip_Address+x}"  ]` hack would be _satisfactory_.  Empirical evidence and _google_ brought me here to discover the "`-v ip_Address`" ... _path_  well done @chepner.  Just looking for documentation ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `bash` 4.2 (the latest, although 4.3 should be released soon...), you can use the `-v` conditional operator to test if a variable is set.

```
if [[ -v ip_Address ]]; then
    printf "ip_Address is set\n";
fi
```

Note that the argument for `-v` is the *name* of the variable you are testing, so you don't  prefix it with a `$`.

Comment: That's _brilliant_ -- And of course I've been asking myself _Why_ `Bash` doesn't have a "`defined()` function".  Where (though) is this documented?  I have Bash v4.3 and I checked: `man bash`, `man test`, _mythical_ `google` ... still looking.  I did some testing of my own too. ____ `-v ip_Address`, works with just one bracket-pair( `[... ]` ).  Also, it works on a _defined_ variable which was undefined with `unset ip_Address` .  That is very handy for me as I wish to use this _feature_ to turn `UNIT_TEST` **on** / **off** like a light-switch.

Comment: _Seniors moment_; in the old days such arguments and variables were _mostly called_ "`switch`-es", just like _light-switches_.  So if a _`<something>`_ was undefined; it would just be in the state of: `OFF` -- Which would be like: `false`, `00`, `NULL`, _`invalid`_, etc. the suitable _nothing-too-see-here_ state.

Comment: It's in the man page for 4.3 at least (I don't have a 4.2 handy to check), but it's not in alphabetical order with the rest of the operators for conditional expressions. It's near the bottom of the list, just before the string comparison operators like `==` et al.

Comment: Found:  **[Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)** and on man pages via grep.  OK thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can differentiate between unset, set but empty, and non-empty using the `${var-value}` substitutions.

```
case ${ip_address-UNSET} in UNSET) echo "It's unset." ;; esac
case ${ip_address:-EMPTY} in EMPTY) echo "It's set, but empty." ;; esac
case ${ip_address:+SET} in SET) echo "It's set and nonempty." ;; esac
```

This is just for demonstration; your logic would probably look quite different.

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1):

Use test's `-n` flag instead of `-z`.

This will test if the variable has content and will also identify if the variable is unset.

```
if [ -n "$ip_Address" ]
then
    # ip_address is set 
else 
    # ip_address is no content OR is not set
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following lines do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -ne 1;
then
    echo "Usage: check_for_ip.sh infile"
    exit
fi

. $1

test -z "${ip_address}" && echo "No IP address" || echo "IP address is: ${ip_address}"
```

Testfiles:

```
$ cat file1 
ip_address=
filename=test.bin
$ cat file2 
ip_address=10.78.1.0
filename=test.bin
$ cat file3
filename=test.bin
```

Testresults:

```
$ bash check_for_ip.sh file1
No IP address
$ bash check_for_ip.sh file2
IP address is: 10.78.1.0
$ bash check_for_ip.sh file3
No IP address
```

I'm not sure if I understood the problem because this looks mostly like your solution; maybe you just missing the "" in the test.

Comment: As per your result, `case 1` and `case 3`  looks identical which i not want means in `case 1` variable is there but no value so it's ok but in `case 3` variable not available. So require to differentiate this.